# How to show Emoji in UILabel iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilabel, emoji

I have to show the textview text smily in UILabel.

In the `UILabel` -

```
lbl.text = @"Happy to help you \U0001F431;
```

its showing properly.

In `UITextView` -

I tried to convert `UITextView` text in string and then log is -

```
%F0%9F%99%88%F0%9F%99%89%F0%9F%99%8A
```

How to encode which i can show in `UILabel`, anybody please suggest me.

Comment: Hey @Arun Sharma Check my updated answer.,,,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"Happy to help you \U0001F431";

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSData *dataa = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

_lbl.text = valueEmoj;
```

**SWIFT - 3 OR HIGHER**

```
    let str = "Happy to help you \U0001F431"

    let data : NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let valueUnicode : String = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let dataa   : NSData = valueUniCode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let valueEmoj : String = String(data: dataa, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!
```

**SWIFT - 4 OR HIGHER**

```
    let str = "Happy to help you \U0001F431"

    let data : NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let valueUnicode : String = String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    let dataa   : NSData = valueUnicode.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
    let valueEmoj : String = String(data: dataa as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)!
```

Comment: Let me try, if it works. Before one was returning null.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, You have any idea how i can convert in hex ?

Comment: @gstream79 please print your string here

Answer (score 49):

You can use `⌃ ⌘ Space` shortcut to show the symbols panels and just insert the emoji you're looking for directly without unicode:

```
lbl.text = @"Happy to help you ";
```

(just copy the code above to Xcode if you browser doesn't show the emoji)

Comment: For those with a different keyboard on mine its ⌘+ctrl+Space

Answer (score 8):

On Xcode version 7.2.1,
You can use the below shortcut to show the symbols panels and insert the emoji:

**shortcut:**
*(pressed the below three keys together)*

```
Ctrl Command Space
```

Answer (score 6):

***Swift 3.0* solution** update given by @Bhavesh Nayi

```
    let data =  txtMessage.text!.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
    let emojiString = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
```

and Send it to Chat Server as a

```
    let data = message.message.data(using: .utf8)
    let emoji = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
```

and Then Show emoji to UILablel

Answer (score 4):

**In case of swift 2.3 or lower**

```
let textViewData : NSData = textViewString.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!
let valueUniCode : String = String(data: textViewData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let emojData   : NSData = valueUniCode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let emojString : String = String(data: emojData, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)!
```

In Case of **Swift 3.0 or higher**

```
let textViewData = textViewString.data(using: .nonLossyASCII)
let valueUniCode = String.init(data: textViewData!, encoding: .utf8)!

let emojData   = valueUniCode.data(using: .utf8)
let emojString = String.init(data: emojData, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
```