# iOS 10: Emoji on UIButton

Tags: ios, emoji, ios10

On iOS 9 I used to do this

`[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Problem: now I'm building with the iOS 10 SDK and instead it is showing three dots next to each other. It works fine on `UILabel`.
Also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671591/1352169), but didn't work.

Any idea how you'd do emoji in iOS 10? Swift answers would be great too.

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me, but ellipsis tend to imply that the button's extents aren't big enough for the text that's being used. You should check the constraints that the button's operating on.

Comment: @VarunKumar No, that is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 10 seems to use an ever so slightly bigger font. Either make your button bigger or setup the button's label to auto adjust the font's size to fit its title.

A label shows `...` by default when the text won't fit.

Comment: It worked but my font-size didn't change, and it still increased? Any idea how happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unicode` to set emoji as `button` title see below code:

```
[self.btn setTitle:@"\U0001F47B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Just replace `+` character with three `000` and backward slash as prefix of `unicode`. Here is the [list](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) of `emoji` with its `unicodes`.

Comment: Sorry but this answer won't fix anything. There's no reason that simply changing the Emoji literal to it's Unicode escape sequence will make any difference. At runtime this code is the same as the OP's code. The Unicode escape will be translated to the literal characters at compile time.

Comment: @rmaddy feeling informative to have your contribution here ..thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Do nonlossy string encoding:

```
NSData *Data=[@"youremojistring" dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *result=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
[button setTitle:result forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Why is this up voted? It's wrong and won't fix anything.