# UILabel display emojis

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` which is displaying emojis incorrectly.

Here is a screenshot from iOS app:
[image]

And here is a screenshot from Android app which is displaying the same text with the emoji correctly.
[image]

I have tried answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670959/how-to-show-emoji-in-uilabel-ios) but they did not help.

Example string : `"تم البيع والله يبارك للمشتري&hearts;️"`

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:comment.body];
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];

NSDictionary *attributesDictionary;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle =
[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
paragraphStyle.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true;

attributesDictionary = @{
                         NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                         NSFontAttributeName : cellFont,
                         NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                         NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                         };

[str addAttributes:attributesDictionary
             range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

cell.commentTextLabel.attributedText = str;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see `&hearts;️`, is that a normal "HTML standard"? Because I'd say it needs a custom parsing (like: `[... replaceOccurencesOf:@"&hearts" with: @"HeartEmoji"];️`). And `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`  and `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` aren't needed in your code. They are skipped by the compiler.

Comment: @Larme I forgot to mention that the original response is in UTF-8. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/gf3vjXtu

Comment: and if it requires parsing to "HeartEmoji" then why does it show fine in android and web without parsing. It won't be easy to write something like this for all the emojis. There has to be some other way.

Comment: Because iOS and Android use different standard libraries? I don't know if `&hearts;` is natively parsed as such in iOS, and even in iOS lib. And it's a "specific" emoji, no really an emoji. And again, `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute` doesn't work in your code, it's not like that. I think you might need to mix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670959/how-to-show-emoji-in-uilabel-ios & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Comment: I did some more readings on the issue and the links that you shared. After converting the string to NSData and choosing NSUTF16 encoding and then creating an NSAttributed string, it now shows the emoji. But some how this code is also removing new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the emoji's unicode.
in your case, the unicode for the red heart is: U+2764 U+FE0F .

- Objective C code :

  ```
  cell.commentTextLabel.text = @"تم البيع والله يبارك للمشتري \U00002764 \U0000FE0F";
  ```
- Swift code:

  ```
  cell.commentTextLabel.text = "تم البيع والله يبارك للمشتري \u{2764} \u{FE0F}"
  ```

For more emojis, In Xcode go **Edit** -> **Emoji & Symbols**, choose an emoji then right click on it and click **Copy Character Info** Button. Paste it and you will get for the red heart:

```
❤️
red heart
Unicode: U+2764 U+FE0F, UTF-8: E2 9D A4 EF B8 8F
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following code:

```
    NSData *data = [comment.body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:false];

    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc ] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary;
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle =
    [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    attributesDictionary = @{
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
        NSFontAttributeName : cellFont
    };

    [str addAttributes:attributesDictionary range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

    cell.commentTextLabel.attributedText = str;
```

In here `comment.body` is the string fetched from server which contains the emoji.

The result was like this:

[image]

Thanks to Larme for his help in the comments.